# How read a local xml file in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read a local xml file from res/xml/myxml.xml
This is the xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Books>
  <Number id ="1">
    <Description>This is science book.
    </Description>
  </Number> 
  <Number id = "2">
    <Description>This is about cooking.
   </Description>
  </Number>
</Books>
```

Here is the code,

```
XmlResourceParser pars = res.getXml(R.xml.myxml);
while (pars.getEventType() != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (pars.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
              if(pars.getName().equals("Number")) {
                   int id = pars.getAttributeIntValue(null, "id", 0);
              }
        }
    pars.next();
}
pars.close();
```

The above code returns the last id of the xml.
How can I check to see if the id == certain integer, than display the description in the textview.
Sorry I am new to android and java. I will really appreciate your help.
Thanks