# How to parse a local XML file in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I want to retrieve data from an xml file in android app. Below is the code I am working with. I think the if statements I am using are not working well ( they are not picking the description to display). I want to display the text(description) if the id value is for example 2. Please review the code and help me correct it.Thanks.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Books> 
  <Number id ="1"> 
    <Description>This text is for id whose value is equal to 1. </Description> 
  </Number> 
  <Number id = "2"> 
    <Description>This text is for id whose value is equal to 2. </Description> 
  </Number> 
</Books>
```

```java
String stringXmlContent;
try {
    stringXmlContent = getEventsFromAnXML(this);
    tv.setText(stringXmlContent);
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

button1.setOnClickListener(this);

private String getEventsFromAnXML(Activity activity)throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{
     StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
     String attVal = null;
     String desc;
     Resources res = activity.getResources();
     XmlResourceParser xrp = res.getXml(R.xml.myxml);
     try {
            xrp.next();
            int eventType = xrp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
            {
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    stringBuffer.append(" ");
                }
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                {    
                  if(xrp.getName().equals("Number")){    
                     attVal =  xrp.getAttributeValue(0); 
                  }       
                }
                else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                {    
                   if(xrp.getName().equals("Description") && attVal.equals("2")){
                   stringBuffer.append(" " + xrp.getText());
                }   

            }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return stringBuffer.toString();  
}
```

Comment: You've asked exactly this question countless times before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118382/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106178, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089092, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102872/having-problem-in-retrieving-data-from-res-xml-books-xml-in-android and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079570/need-help-in-reading-an-xml-file. Plese do not repeat the same question over and over. Just edit the original question to improve it and describe the problem better whenever the answers are not satisfying and also communicate with the answerers.